# É possível criar tabela vazia com ireport?

Tags: ireport

Meu problema parece simples, mas não estou conseguindo.
Atualmente o relatório é impresso com um espaço em branco para o docente inserir o conteúdo programático de suas aulas, ele coloca data e o conteúdo. Alguns abrem o relatório no word e inserem por lá uma tabela.

Para facilitar a vida deles me pediram para inserir uma tabela com 2 colunas e espaços em brancos.

Não encontrei essa opção na tabela do ireport. Até conseguir criar uma tabela vazia, mas não vi opções pra criar múltiplas linhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, as linhas são dinâmicas, elas aparecem conforme você alimenta sua tabela, disponha de mais detalhes.
O que você pode fazer é criar uma tabela fixa com `label's` vazio e com bordas visíveis. e os campos que forem exibir informações `textfield's` com bordas também. Neste caso você adiciona uma linha, para cada registro ele escreve os dados nos `textfild's` e desenha um `label` pra adicionar a informação do jeito que você pretende.